# Concurrency example confusion

Tags: go, concurrency

I’m studying concurrency in more depth with Go. A book I am reading gives the following example, which basically compresses files from command line argument(s).

```
 package main

 import (
  "compress/gzip"
  "io"
  "os"
 )

 func main() {

     for _, file := range os.Args[1:] {
        compress(file)
     }

 }


 func compress(filename string) error {

     in, err := os.Open(filename)

     if err != nil {
      return err
     }

     defer in.Close()

     out, err := os.Create(filename + ".gz")

     if err != nil {
       return err
     }

     defer out.Close()

     gzout := gzip.NewWriter(out)

     _, err = io.Copy(gzout, in)

     gzout.Close()

     return err
}
```

The book then explains that if you wanted to process a few hundred files, keeping it like this would definitely be slower than if you were to utilise goroutines, so the following modification is made to the `main()` function in order to use them:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup 
var i int = -1
var file string
for i, file = range os.Args[1:] {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(filename string) {
       compress(filename)
       wg.Done()
     }(file)
 }
 wg.Wait()
 fmt.Printf("Compressed %d files\n", i+1)
```

It is then noted that the “trickery” with regard to the inline function definition and its parameter (file name), is necessary “because we are executing goroutines in a for loop”.

I guess what I don’t understand is why the above inline function is required to get this working, couldn’t the following be used instead, or am I missing a trick?

```
for i, file = range os.Args[1:] {
    wg.Add(1)

    go compress(file)

    wg.Done()

 }
 wg.Wait()
 fmt.Printf("Compressed %d files\n", i+1)
```

Comment: Your version doesn't use concurrency. So it would work, but sequentially. Which also means that all your `wg` calls are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the Go keyword for the function though. Editing a SO question on a tablet is the last thing Ill do ever again.

Comment: The current version doesn't wait for `compress` to finish before calling `wg.Done()`

Comment: Cheers, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just execute:

```
compress(file)
```

That gets executed in the same goroutine, so until that call finishes, you won't be doing anything else.

So if you want to process in parallel, then you need to launch a new goroutine by using the `go` keyword.

If you do this:

```
go compress(file)
```

Then *it will* launch a new goroutine for compressing each file.

But, as soon as the `main` function launches all goroutines, it will end execution (it will not wait for all goroutines to finish).

That's why they included the `wg` calls.

Since the `compress` function does not receive a `WaitGroup` to call the `Done` over it, they implemented that inline function in order to call `wg.Done()` right after that goroutine finishes the compression over that file.

That's the reason for the:

```
go func(filename string) {
    compress(filename)
    wg.Done()
}(file)
```

Comment: Also worth pointing out that it would be insufficient to use something like `go func() { compress(file); wg.Done() }()`, i.e. without the `filename` argument. This is because range loops reuse the iteration variable so the `file` gets overwritten on each iteration and if you reference it inside a goroutine closure (`go func() { file }()`) then its value will be from the last executed iteration *at the time* of the var's evaluation. On the other hand when you pass it as an argument, a copy is created and so `filename` will always have the value of the iteration that called the goroutine.